# Erro ao compilar PhoneGap

Tags: java, android, linux, apache-cordova, terminal

Ao executar o comando para compilar o phonegap

```
phonegap build android
```

Mas apresenta um erro:

```
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android'...
Running command: /var/www/gabriel/phonegap/teste/platforms/android/cordova/build 

[Error: Failed to run "java -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.]

ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /var/www/gabriel/phonegap/teste/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

Error: /var/www/gabriel/phonegap/teste/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
```

Java ta instalado normal: ( java -version )

```
java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.15.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)
```

O que pode ser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia meu caro,

o problema está com o tipo de JAVA instalado na sua máquina o `OpenJDK`

o ideal é remover o `OpenJDK` e instalar o `Oracle JDK` no lugar

abaixo o comando remove o `OpenJDK`, entre no terminal como root

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openjdk-*
```

OBS: são dois traços antes de purge.

Agora vamos adicionar o PPA para baixar e instalar o Oracle Java (JDK), depois você poderá escolher se que instalar a versão 7 ou 8. Ainda no terminal, digite uma linha de cada vez:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
```

Se quiser instalar o Java versão 7 execute:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Se quiser instalar o Java versão 8 execute:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Esse processo ira baixar e instalar o Java da Oracle automaticamente!

Certamente você não terá mais o problema mencionado! Saude!